# Attitude matrix and connection forms

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I'm stuck trying to proof this theorem presented at [Elementary Differential Geometry O'Neil](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=HrriBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Elementary%20Differential%20Geometry&ots=c9ycI8xtXx&sig=HY-c5R5cFe6-7xVAy5UF7NNifGM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Elementary%20Differential%20Geometry&f=false) :

**Theorem** : If $A=(a_{ij})$ is the attitude matrix and $\omega=(\omega_{ij})$ the matrix of connections forms of a frame field $E_1,\dotsm, E_n$, then $\omega=dA.A^{T}$

We have that $a_{ij}=<E_i,U_j>$ where $U_j$ is the natural frame and $\omega_{ij}(v)=<\nabla_v E_i,E_j>$ is the connection form related to the frame field $E_1,\dotsm,E_j$.

My guest is: we know that A is orthogonal, so $A^{-1}=A^T$; thus $\omega.A=dA$ and just use these definitions, but I'm doing something wrong... thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ is the matrix whose row vectors are the vectors $E_i$ written in terms of the standard basis $U_j$. So
$$\omega_{ij}= \langle\nabla E_i,E_j\rangle = \langle dE_i,E_j\rangle = (dA\,A^\top)_{ij},$$
as required.

Comment: I don't undertood why $\nabla E_i = dE_i$, because if I use that $E_i=A_i^k.U_k$, by product rule I'll have two terms: $dA.U$ and $A.\nabla U$

Comment: The $U_k$ are constant vectors. I don't know why O'Neil is using the $\nabla$ notation when we're working on Euclidean space, as opposed to taking the covariant derivative on a surface.

Comment: Well, that makes a lot of sense.